# Excel Web Query references break when saving worksheet

Tags: excel, openxml, excel-web-query

When I modify an existing Excel workbook containing web queries, any new web queries I add will work fine until I save and reopen the document. When I reopen, suddenly all tables return the same data because (somehow) the `query` parameter for the new queries has been replaced with the first query added to the document.

I.e., when I reopen the document and review the query parameters, they all look like this:

[image: Screenshot of Query]

So I decided to explore the XML inside the xlsx workbook to see what was going on. Turns out all my new queries are there in the `/xl/queryTables/` path but they all reference the same data connection (connections are referenced by `id` number), and alas, `/xl/connections.xml` has no mention of the new data connections I created.

So then I thought I would be clever and just create some new nodes in `connections.xml` then reference the correct connections by their corresponding `id`. Unfortunately Excel decided this was no good and decided to "repair" my workbook by breaking it back to the broken way it was before.

Does anyone know of a fix, hack or workaround? There must be some way to get new queries to save in a workbook.

**[My Environment]**: Excel Mac 2011 Version 14.2.4 (120824) - latest build as of writing; MacOS Mountain Lion 10.8.2.